# Query SQL database using power automate desktop

Tags: power-automate

I'm trying to get data in a variable from SQL database using power automate desktop.
I have succesfully created SQL srver connection and have executed Query, but I'm unable to get the value of that column in a variable.

My query is returning only single value, but when i query the output which is by default in the data table format, I'm only getting the name of the column and the count, but unable to get the value.

Below are the screenshot, one is of the database where I have executed query and output is returned

[image: SQL Server Database query output]

and second one is of the output I'm getting in the query table using SQL server in power automate

Image of how I have user Query parameter to display the result.

[image: Image of how I have user Query parameter to display the result.]

[image: and the output of it]

Answer (score 0):

In Power Automate Desktop you can access a specific column like this:

`%QueryResult[0]%` or `%QueryResult[1]%`.